# Cyberduck：Remove FTP protocol from ConnectionForm comboBox

Tags: ftp, protocols, cyberduck

I'm now doing the second development of Cyberduck(using **C#**). As we can see,there are many protocols when we open the Cyberduck client,and we can use different protocol to connect,such as FTP、Swift、or S3.

Then how to remove these protocols in the ConnectionForm ComboBox? **I just need Swift,and i want to remove the FTP protocol in this comboBox.** I have been trying for a few days,but still can not ***remove the FTP protocol***. Who can help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
 I modified the "InitProtocol" method, to make sure that only the protocols i need were added to the comboBox.